# NumberFormatter::CURRENCY having issue with de_CH.utf-8 code

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am using numfmt_format_currency() for formatting the currency in my site and its working in most of the currency except the swiss currency CHF.

```
$num = 'CHF 40.00';
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_CH', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
numfmt_parse_currency($fmt, $num, $curr);
```

I am getting an error: `string 'Number parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR'` 
I tried the same code by using USD and it works fine

```
$num = '$43.87';
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
numfmt_parse_currency($fmt, $num, $curr);
```

I tried a lot with other currencies too and they are working fine, I searched out in google but didn't get any help.
If someone knows whats wrong in the code please let me know.

Comment: Is the `de_CH` locale installed? Check what locales are available with `locale -a`.

Comment: Which PHP version do you use? And which ICU version ist installed (`php -i | grep ICU`)?

Comment: It has the locale installed - de_CH,de_CH.iso88591,de_CH.utf8

Comment: ICU version is 4.4.1 @StefanGehrig